# Escape an entire string variable which MAY contain characters that need escaping

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My PowerShell V3 creates an Office 365 user based on a series of questions, and then sends an email to the IT team with the details. The problematic bit is:

```
#Generate-RandomPassword
$xpassword = Create-ComplexPassword -PasswordLength 14 -LowerAlphas 1 -UpperAlphas 1 -Numbers 1 -SpecialCharacters 1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($xpassword)


Write-Host 'Sending Email' -foregroundcolor yellow
$xbody =  "<head>"
$xbody += "<style>"
$xbody += "p{"
$xbody += "font-family:Verdana;"
$xbody += "font-size:10pt;"
$xbody += "margin-top:0;"
$xbody += "margin-bottom:0;"
$xbody += "}"
$xbody += "</style>"
$xbody += "</head>"
$xbody += "<p>Password: <span style=`"font-family:'Lucida Console',sans serif;font-size:10pt;color:red`">$xpassword</span>"
$xbody += "<p>License: $xk1ore1"
$xbody += "<p>Country: $xcountry"
$xbody += "<p>Town: $xtown"
$xbody += "<p>Status: $xstatus"
$xbody += "<p>Laptop User: $xlaptopuser"
$xbody += "<p>CRM User: $xcrm"
$xbody += "<p>Operations Mailbox Access: $xoperations"
$xbody += "<p>Finance Mailbox Access: $xfinance"
$xbody += "<p>IT Support Mailbox Access: $xitsupport"
$xbody += "<p>Hide from GAL: $xhidefromgal"

Send-O365MailMessage -To itsupport@blah.com -Subject "O365 Account Created" -Body "$xbody" -BodyAsHtml -Credential $cred
```

The variable $xpassword may include characters that need escaping, and may not. When the password contains a '<' for example, I get this as one line in my email:

```
Password: 4*#<(OGyq<="" span="">
```

How can I cater for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .net library:

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode()
```

and `::HtmlDecode` to read encoded strings.

Edit:
I can see that you pasted your script. And there's an error.
The method HtmlEncode() return System.String, so change this:

```
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($xpassword)
```

To this:

```
$xpassword=[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode($xpassword)
```

Otherwise your script will only print the encoded string, and $xpassword stays the same.

Comment: Ah, no, actually I'm still getting **Password: .kSA|k9<V<S8d7< span="">** in my html emails.

Comment: @finisterre 
Ok, I don't get it now.. You have $xpassword variable that may contain tag-like strings (<span> for example), that you don't want to be interpreted as HTML tags, only printed out? If this is the case, my solution is right.
Please edit your question and post the exact value of your variable, and what the output (html view) should be.

Comment: Mo. The password will only contain character a-z, A-Z, 1-9 and special chars. But I think the fact that some of these special chars are breaking it. Particualrly '<' it seems. I then generate an email that sends the password to people.

Comment: Ah, of course. I should have figured that. Works now. Thanks.